# Hibernate: Generate dynamic POJO classes & Mapping files at RUNTIME

Tags: java, hibernate, dynamic, jboss

I am looking for a way to generate hibernate classes with XML mapping files at runtime.
Using hibernate can save much more time than dealing with database myself using JDBC for example.

Suppose I generated the POJO .java class, .class (ByteCode) with [javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) library and it's .hbm.xml mapping file with the right syntax, will hibernate recognize it automatically without any additional configurations, or this process must be done at startup and requires application restarting?
If so What are those extra steps that are done on startup and can I do it at runtime?

I searched a lot and read about [Hibernate Dynamic Models](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels) but what if I need to connect and deal with some tables of the database before classes generation phase?

I read also about **Ant Task** and **Spring Roo** but still confused where to go..

Has anyone handled such this thing before?

Your advice please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm, I don't think that this make sense. Your program must know the classes at compiletime because otherwise you weren't able to use them in your program.

Comment: If you want to do the Graal (but you will be alone to understand and maintain it) you can redefine a ClassLoader that when it detects a class missing that would have the name of an entity you want to offer, creates a temporary and custom Java source file (by parsing and understanding the wishes of your XML file), compile it with the internal JavaCompiler class available since JDK 6, and then offer it as if I was provided by the jar at the launch of your program. But beware : this is doable (really : it should work), but be unreachable for a beginner or a medium developper level.

Answer (score 0):

I like what you are trying to do, so I will contribute when you said:

Will hibernate recognize it automatically without any additional configurations, or this process must be done at startup and requires application restarting?

Hibernate will recognise it but with additional modifications to hibernate.cfg file, i.e, you need to add mapping properties for each entity, and this `requires` application restarting.

To avoid restarting your server I can only imagin deploying the application at runtime on a second server- after generating the required resources, if the first start up could be in the background that would make things better.